# How to POST correctly to a bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-data

So im implmenting an API using springboot, spring-data and Jackson, but im having some troubles when im trying to POST a request to an endpoint who have a Bidirection relationship of @OneToMany.

I dont have so much background so i need really help.

I have two Entities:

Partida

```java
package lucas.duarte.jazz.model.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Entity
public class Partida implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String timeA;
    private String timeB;
    private boolean visitante;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "partida", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Set> sets;


    public List<Set> getSets() {
        return sets;
    }

    public void setSets(List<Set> sets) {
        this.sets = sets;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTimeA() {
        return timeA;
    }

    // Mocado o valor pois o Time A sempre e a Sao Judas
    public void setTimeA(String timeA) {
        this.timeA = timeA;
    }

    public String getTimeB() {
        return timeB;
    }

    public void setTimeB(String timeB) {
        this.timeB = timeB;
    }

    public boolean isVisitante() {
        return visitante;
    }

    public void setVisitante(boolean visitante) {
        this.visitante = visitante;
    }

}
```

and SET

```java
package lucas.duarte.jazz.model.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@Entity
@Table(name = "meu_set")
public class Set implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "ponto_a")
    private long pontoA;
    @Column(name = "ponto_b")
    private long pontoB;
    @Column(name = "set_finalizado")
    private boolean setFinalizado;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "partida_id")
    private Partida partida;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getPontoA() {
        return pontoA;
    }

    public void setPontoA(long pontoA) {
        this.pontoA = pontoA;
    }

    public long getPontoB() {
        return pontoB;
    }

    public void setPontoB(long pontoB) {
        this.pontoB = pontoB;
    }

    public boolean isSetFinalizado() {
        return setFinalizado;
    }

    public void setSetFinalizado(boolean setFinalizado) {
        this.setFinalizado = setFinalizado;
    }

    public Partida getPartida() {
        return partida;
    }

    public void setPartida(Partida partida) {
        this.partida = partida;
    }

}
```

This is my SetControler

```java
package lucas.duarte.jazz.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import lucas.duarte.jazz.model.bean.Set;
import lucas.duarte.jazz.model.service.SetService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SetController {

    private SetService setServ;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/set/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> salvarSet(@RequestBody Set set, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        System.out.println("Vou cadastrar um set vinculado a uma partida");
        System.out.println(set.getPartida().getId());
        setServ.salvarSet(set);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

**When i POST to the URL, i get the following return**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-28T04:17:46.857+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `lucas.duarte.jazz.model.bean.Partida` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `lucas.duarte.jazz.model.bean.Partida` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 14] (through reference chain: lucas.duarte.jazz.model.bean.Set[\"partida\"])",
    "path": "/api/set/"
}
```

**I Already have a Partida inside my database, but i cannot POST to this method, need really help.**

Comment: please define default constructor public Partida (){}

Comment: For deserialisation purposes Partida class must have a zero-arg constructor.

Comment: Show the json body you're trying to send to this endpoint

Comment: ```{ 
 "pontoA" : 1,
 "pontoB" : 1,
 "setFinalizado" : "false",
 "partida_id" : 1
 
}
```
Json Body of my request

Comment: @LucasDuarte try This {
 "partida_id": 1,
 "pontoA": 1,
 "pontoB": 1,
 "setFinalizado": "false"
}

Comment: not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with JPA bi-directional mapping. Its raising error at the time of de serializing.
Partida -> should have zero argument constructor

Request payload should have { "partida":{"id":123}} in order to populate partida object property.

Comment: When i tried this, i got the follow 2019-03-28 02:48:17.679 ERROR 8180 --- [nio-5888-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

Comment: You were right, just the way who i pass the JSON, and the null pointer exeception was because i forgot the @Autowired annotation tho inject the dependencie.

Comment: Thats good news at least json error is gone.  private SetService setServ;  is null and any operation in the object will throw null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

for details check this link [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library.

```
@Entity
public class Partida implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String timeA;
    private String timeB;
    private boolean visitante;
    public  Partida(){
    //Default constructor required here 
    }
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "partida", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = 
    CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Set> sets;


    public List<Set> getSets() {
        return sets;
    }

    public void setSets(List<Set> sets) {
        this.sets = sets;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTimeA() {
        return timeA;
    }

    // Mocado o valor pois o Time A sempre e a Sao Judas
    public void setTimeA(String timeA) {
        this.timeA = timeA;
    }

    public String getTimeB() {
        return timeB;
    }

    public void setTimeB(String timeB) {
        this.timeB = timeB;
    }

    public boolean isVisitante() {
        return visitante;
    }

    public void setVisitante(boolean visitante) {
        this.visitante = visitante;
    }

}
```

if issue not not resolved then try JSON creator

```
@JsonCreator
    public Partida(@JsonProperty("id") Long id, @JsonProperty("timeA") String 
    timeA, @JsonProperty("timeB") String timeB, @JsonProperty("desc") boolean
    visitante) {
    this.id = id;
    this.timeA = timeA;
    this.timeB= timeB;
    this.visitante= visitante;
}
```

Comment: It does not work eaither, i tried with the empty constructor and with the annotatio @JsonCreator, the serveris always the same error

Comment: @LucasDuarte: create an empty constructor in your set class public Set(){} and after that share your error message